# i am getting Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "FUNCTION": invalid identifier in hibernate JPA 3.6.7.final version

Tags: jpa

String queryString="select model.vesselCode,model.vesselName,count(model) from Vesselarrivalnotice model where model.vesselCode is not null and "+ 
            "model.vesselName is not null and model.docStatus='Approved' and function('MONTH',model.actualArriveTime)="+month+" and function('YEAR',model.actualArriveTime)="+year+
            " and model.portdetailCode='"+port+"' and model.companydetailCode='"+company+"' "+
            " group by model.vesselCode,model.vesselName";

```
    Query query = getKpiEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
```

Comment: Why don'tyou use `setParameter`. `function` is not valid, means your orm cannot distinguish what is it. So you should not use it. The jpa query you write must meet the criteria of the orm not database. So make sure your orm (hibernate in your case) understands your query

Comment: Perhaps your JPA implementation doesn't support JPA 2.1 (i.e use of FUNCTION). Get a JPA implementation that does support JPA 2.1

Answer (score 0):

The `createQuery` method expects a `JPQL` query and you are providing a `SQL` query. `JPQL` is similar to `SQL` but has a different syntax and is not as powerful as `SQL`.
You have two options:

1. `use getKpiEntityManager().createNativeQuery(queryString)` to execute an `SQL` query,
2. rewrite your query to `JPQL`. But `JPQL` does not support functions, so option 1 might be the better/easier choice.